# Iframe src depending device width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am doing a web page, and in this I have ads.

I do the ads with Google Web Designer, this program generates an iframe.

In function of the client device, specifically the width of this device, I want to show a specific iframe. How can I specify the src of the iframe that want I to show, in function of the device-width?

I try using media queries in CSS to hide all iframes except the correct, but it is not work correctly; I try it in Windows Phone and Android.

Offtopic: if anyone know a software better than Google Web Designer, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, say your iFrame has an id "frame"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;

if(width == 950)
   $('#frame').attr('src',url);
else if(width == 750)
   $('#frame').attr('src',url2);
...
...
...
</script>
```

Comment: It works. And how can I capture the event when the user rotate his smartphone? To change the src if the width changes...

Comment: I test the code in Windows Phone and works correctly, but in Android don't show any frame.